# Call a web service from .net code

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to create an application in Visual Studio 2015 that calls a web service set up on one of our servers (It's a third party web service so I don't really know anything about its implementation).

I can browse to the web service definition, and view the wsdl and singleWsdl definitions.

In Visual Studio, I right-click on the Service References folder and choose 'Add Service Reference...', type in the URL to the web service (I've also tried the wsdl and singleWsdl URLs which produce the same result) and click 'Go'.  The operations are shown, so I enter a namespace and click 'OK'.

At this point lots of code is generated, but, and I think this is the cause of my problem, there are **no changes made to the config file**.

When I try and run my code I get an error:

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find default endpoint element that
>   references contract 'CRMContactEventService.ContactEventService' in
>   the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because
>   no configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client
>   element."

I've tried using SvcUtil.exe to generate the proxy but it also does not generate any config file.  I've tried using wsdl.exe to generate another wsdl file but that just generates an empty file.  I've tried saving the singleWsdl file to my local drive and using that instead of the URL but the results are the same.

Now after lots of searching, I have tried to manually add what I think is missing to the web.config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://...<url to service>.../ContactEventService.svc"
                binding ="netHttpBinding"
                contract = "CRMContactEventService.ContactEventService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This changes the error message:

> "An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://....../ContactEventService.svc that could
>   accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

InnerException contains:

> "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

I have tried several different values for the binding parameter in the web.config file as I don't know which one to use, but most return the above error or some other error which makes it clear that I made a bad choice.

I've been looking at this problem for far too long and I cannot see how to get this working, or even whether it's a problem with what I am doing or a problem with the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Can you first manually make the SOAP call to the actual service endpoint and check if you're getting the expected result? The free [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) client is very useful for this type of troubleshooting. (Having said that, if the remote endpoint is responding correctly, I think you're on the right path to figuring this out.)

Comment: Ok, I created a project in SoapUI, gave it the location of the WSDL file and ticked "Create Requests" and "Create TestSuite".  It loaded the definitions and then nothing - no error message and the project is still empty.  At this stage I think I will have to go back to the third party and suggest that they check their web service is functioning correctly.